# latex2html: Includes junk from document preamble and other mess.

Tags: conversion, html, latex2html

I'm trying to make a clean web-version of a significantly sized tex document. latex2html works 'ok' except for not being able to handle lots of packages. Thats not a problem since I'm not that worried about style in this case, but all of the guff from those style related commands is treated as plain text.

Is there a way of getting latex2html to effectively say 'I don't know what that is so I'm going to forget about it at all?'

Comment: please add a minimal example of your LaTeX code that reproduces the problem.